# Compare content of rows in two different sheets if content of the first cell is true

Tags: vba, excel

What I am trying to do is coding a macro that compares the rows in sheet1 and sheet2 and highlights the differences. You can see the macro for that below.

My problem is that in case a row or more is added or deleted in the first sheet, all other rows shift up/down which results in a lot of cells being marked in the second sheet.

Since I have an identifier in column A I try to implement an extra line which first looks for the same identifier in sheet 1 and once found, compares the rows of sheet 1 and sheet two, which have the same identifier and then marks potential differences.

Since all my ideas have failed so far, or made the file very slow, I hope you can help me out.
Thank you very much!

```
Sub comparing()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
Dim rCount As Long, cCount As Long
Set sh1 = Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count() - 1)
Set sh2 = Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
rCount = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
cCount = sh1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Dim r As Long, c As Integer
For r = 1 To rCount
    For c = 1 To cCount
        If sh1.Cells(r, c) <> sh2.Cells(r, c) Then
           sh2.Cells(r, c).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End If
    Next c
Next r
Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Select
```

End Sub

Comment: Is sheet2 remain unchange at all time?

Comment: Sheet2 remains unchanged, yes.

Comment: Think JNevill provide an answer already.  Meanwhile I will suggest to create identifier for sheet 1 only, base on the row number on sheet 2 since sheet 2 wont' change.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't fully tested this, but you could use the worksheetfunction `match` inside your first for loop to find the corresponding Row in the second sheet:

```
Sub comparing()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim rCount As Long, cCount As Long
    Set sh1 = Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count() - 1)
    Set sh2 = Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
    rCount = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    cCount = sh1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Dim r As Long, c As Integer, sh2Row As Long
    For r = 1 To rCount
        'Find the matching row in Sheet2 by using the value in Column A from both sheets
        sh2Row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(sh1.Cells(r, 1).Value, sh2.Range("A:A"))
        For c = 1 To cCount
            If sh1.Cells(r, c) <> sh2.Cells(sh2Row, c) Then
               sh2.Cells(sh2Row, c).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
    Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your input so far. I tried your code and what happens first is, that it marked cells that were exactly the same. After I added a row in sheet1 I received an error stating that he cant find the matching properties for the WorksheetFunction Object. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Perhaps it didn't set `rCount` correctly? Those Application.WorksheetFunctions can be a little weird about error reporting.